# Solution to Dirichlet boundary problem on the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a solution of the Dirichlet problem on the upper half-plane $\{(u, v) \in \Bbb R  ^2 :v > 0\}$ with limiting value $π$ on that part of the boundary where $|u| > 1$, and
limiting value $0$ on that part of the boundary where $|u| < 1$.

I'm guessing its going  to be a function involving $Arg(u+iv)$ but can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: Can you do it if the parts of the boundary are $\{ (u,v) : u < 0\}$ and $\{ (u,v) : u > 0\}$?

Comment: $Arg(u+iv)$ would work for $\pi$ on $u<0$ and $0$ on $u>0$, so its then a case of transforming these boundaries into the ones in the question?

Comment: Right. You use a property of the interplay between holomorphic and harmonic functions for that.